# SQL Server: loop once a month value to the whole month

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that gets one value of only one day in each month. I want to duplicate that value to the whole month until a new value shows up. the result will be a table with data for each day of the month based on the last known value.

Can someone help me writing this query?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, due to a lack of consumable sample data, but this looks like a gaps and island problem. Here you can count the number of non-NULL values for `Yield` to assign the group "number" and then get the windowed `MAX` in the outer `SELECT`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Yield,
           [Date],
           COUNT(yield) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT MAX(yield) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS yield
       [Date],
       DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[Date]) AS [Day]
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have data on the first of the month.  That suggests an alternative approach:

```
select t.*, t2.yield as imputed_yield
from t cross apply
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.date = datefromparts(year(t.date), month(t.date), 1)
     ) t2;
```

This should be able to take advantage of an index on `(date, yield)`.  And it does assume that the value you want is on the first date of the month.